# Why csv file doesnt show special characters when export?

Tags: c#, forms

I have this code used on my application to export datagridview as csv file.It worked fine but csv doesnt show cell values correctly.See below images and I have pasted my code as well.What can I change on this code to fix this?

Here is the datagridview

[image]

This is the exported csv and it shows like this

[image]

Here is my code

```
public void writeCSV(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFile)  
    {  

        //test to see if the DataGridView has any rows  
        if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)  
        {  
            string value = "";  
            DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();  
             StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);  


            //write header rows to csv  
            for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)  
            {  
                if (i > 0)  
                {  
                    swOut.Write(",");  
                }  
                swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[i].HeaderText);  
            }  

            swOut.WriteLine();  

            //write DataGridView rows to csv  
            for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 2; j++)  
            {  
                if (j > 0)  
                {  
                    swOut.WriteLine();  
                }  

                dr = gridIn.Rows[j];  

                for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)  
                {  
                    if (i > 0)  
                    {  
                        swOut.Write(",");  
                    }  

                    value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();  
                    //replace comma's with spaces  
                    value = value.Replace(',', ' ');  
                    //replace embedded newlines with spaces  
                    value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");  

                    swOut.Write(value);  
                }  
            }  
            swOut.Close();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: You could open the CSV in notepad? I bet it's excel destroying the numeric values.

Comment: Look up BOM (byte-order-mark), and note that the difference in numeric precision is the difference between Excel and your application. See [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/displaying-values-with-more-than-12-characters-in-excel/) for your more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the Encoding of the StreamWriter:

```
StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

For example UTF-8.

And the number 5.027E+13 just shown in Excel. You could change the text format of the cells to number and excel will show you the value. Or open the csv file in notepad and you will see, that the numbers are right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper text encoding when exporting data into csv file, like `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter swOut =  new StreamWriter(outputFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Same answer of @NikBo